# Trouble with Yahoo OAuth iOS User Input

Tags: ios, redirect, oauth, yahoo

I am trying to get the user to log in to the Yahoo portal, but I'm not sure how to do it. I made the first step (when getting the token, redirect URL etc.), but now I don't know how to make the second one, so I'll get the token to make actions on mail or w/e. I've read several articles on how to do it, and several include using a php script or gtm, but I didn't achieve anything with them. In addition, I found that Yahoo has some API but it is very outdated (2009) and they've changed some stuff since then.

Anyway, I need some help on how to make this [step](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-userauth.html) in Objective-C, iOS. Any help will be appreciated as I am now learning the basics of OAuth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this [API](http://oauth.io) and it worked flawlessly.